# Why are passwords exportable as plain text in WordPress?

Tags: security, password

On my WordPress 3.9.2 installation can I extract the users plain text passwords by going to Users, select all users, and choosing Bulk Actions Export.

When I look in the mySQL database with phpMyAdmin, the passwords are hashed.

**Question**

How come all user passwords can be exported in plain text, and how can I prevent this?

**Update**

When I either export one user or "Export All Users" I get output similar to this

```
User ID,Username,Payment Status,First Name,Last Name,Address,Zip,City,Country,Date,Sex,Phone no.,Email,Company,Password,TOS,Website,AIM,Yahoo IM,Jabber/Google Talk,Biographical Info,Registered,IP
"31","xxx","paid","Jasmine","Lognnes","xxx","xxx","xxx","","xxx","female","","xxx","xxx","xxx","agree","","","","","","2012-01-26 18:13:19","xxx"
```

Comment: I only see a "Delete" option under "Bulk Actions" in the Users page (WP 3.9.2) with all users selected: http://d.pr/i/M2YO Are you using a plugin to get the user export functionality?

Comment: I don't use Wordpress but I would be shocked if it used two way encryption for passwords by default anyway. It is industry standard to use one way encryption for passwords to prevent anyone from being able to decrypt them. It is not impossible to determine the value of a 1 way encrypted string but it takes a lot of CPU power to do that and is not really feasible to do site wide as you describe for any but the smallest of sites. Whatever you've done to make this possible really needs to be undone. Many places actually have laws which make using 2 way encryption for passwords illegal.

Comment: @Nick Is there a way to figure out which plugin that adds this feature? The site is in production, so I need to be careful.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes A couple of ways you could investigate: (A) Download the whole `/wp-content/plugins/` folder to your machine, then search the `plugins` folder for the word, “Export” [using the command line](http://blamcast.net/articles/recursive-grep-find-strings-files) or a text editor that supports [multi-file search](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html). (B) Recreate the entire site on your local machine, then turn off plugins until the Export feature disappears.

Comment: Are you absolutely _certain_ you are seeing plain text passwords? There has never been such an option in WordPress. It has used phpass since 2.5, and md5 hashes before that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I can see my own password in plain text and other users' makes also sense. When using phpMyADmin they are hashed.

Comment: According to everything I read, WP Passwords are oneway encrypted, and users and passwords are not exportable.  Would you mind posting a screenshot of where you see your password? But not your password...

Comment: @Nick Very nice idea to `grep`. `wp-members` is the only plugin to match `Export All Users`. It looks like it is the login plugin that also saves the plain text passwords. Not sure yet.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes It sounds like that plugin's worth investigating further. It's very hard to export plaintext passwords from the hashed ones stored in the database, but I suppose it's possible that a malicious or poorly thought-out plugin is saving passwords in plain text as they're typed when users log in? It would be worth using PhpMyAdmin to search the database for one of the plaintext passwords too – it might point to the plugin that's added those rows to the database. If you do find the culprit, don't forget to answer your own question – it would be interesting to know more.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes A membership plugin could potentially hook into or replace the site's registration and log-in forms and store initial and updated passwords as plain text somewhere. It sounds like that's what might be happening here. It could be a bug. There's an unresolved ticket [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-member-passwords-are-stored-in-clear-text-in-database-highly-insecure) from a month ago where a user posts the same issue you describe.

Comment: Many of the fields that you list in your example are not from WordPress. You are using a very insecure plugin.

Comment: If you're in the UK, and accepting payments, and have plaintext passwords saved or in a 2 way encryption format, as your question suggests, then you would not be PCI compliant, and your implementation would be illegal

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot export passwords as plaintext in WordPress, because they are not stored in plaintext. What you see here is obviously the result of a very bad plugin.

Fields like `Payment`, `Sex` or `Company` are not even part of the regular WordPress tables.

For the future: Do not install plugins without prior tests and reviews in a safe environment. Use a local setup to find such security problems. Especially when you are dealing with other peoples data, this is a **requirement**.

What you should do now: Disable all plugins until this export is not possible anymore. The last disabled plugin was probably the problem. Find all the tables that it has created, delete those tables. Uninstall that plugin.

Answer (score 8):

It is a bug in `wp-members` plugin. Others have reported the same error.

- http://user-meta.com/forums/topic/able-to-save-plain-text-passwords-as-a-user-meta-value/
- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-member-passwords-are-stored-in-clear-text-in-database-highly-insecure

Comment: The bug here is a poor UI. It seems wp-members allows you add custom fields to the registration form, including "password" field. What is not (understandably) clear to users is that these added fields are just for collecting meta data, and the "password" refers to the HTML input type alone and is nothing to do with the user's WP password, nor comes with any guarantee of storing it securely.

Comment: Toscho already have the votes ;) but I think this comment is a much better answer....

Comment: Actually, this is not a better answer.  It's not a bug in the plugin, but rather "user error."  Of the two posts linked to in this answer, the first one isn't even talking about WP-Members. It's talking about a completely different and unrelated plugin, user meta pro.  And if anyone bothered to read the second post linked to, you'd see the answer to this is due to the way the user configured their custom fields and not something inherent in the plugin. The plugin does not store passwords as plain text, nor as user meta.